# rails authentification with url an to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, authentication

in my rails application i override the id with my own 'token'.
The token is a string value.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    def to_param
        token
    end
end
```

This Token is for the admin and he called this
http://localhost:3000/mymodels/token

Now i have another 'pubtoken' for a publicvisitors.
The Visitor should only see a part of the information eq. the show-method.
If you have token you can administrate the data of MyModel.
http://localhost:3000/mymodels/pubtoken

The Question
How can i define the route for the putoken for the page visitor?
If you have the pubtoken you can "only" see a part of MyModel and do some other actions from associated models and controllers.

can i do something like?

```
def to_param
    token: action edit, destroy, new
    pubtoken: action show
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The clue to the answer likely lies in what you are asking.  Fundamentally, you want to change the way different users VIEW the data.  Altering the model for this is likely not the right path.

The most common approach to your problem is [to use namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing), directing Admin users to a set of urls that support CRUD while sending 'public visitors' to another set of urls that support view-only routes.

Comment: that seems to be what i'm looking for. I will try it in the evening and give feedback. Thanks you for opening my eyes

Comment: This was excatly what i'm looking for. Thanks. I do this so. in my config/routes.rb

`namespace :admin do
    resources :mymodels, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]
  end`

And in my Admin::MyModelsController
`class Admin::MyModelsController < ApplicationController
  # calls the edit view
  def edit
    @mymodel = MyModel.find_by_tokenparams[:id])
  end
end`

In my MyModelController i do `find_by_pubtoken(...)`

Comment: Yes it works, but how do i define different params to enter the datasets. if i define to_param the pubtoken it works for all with the pubtoken. But i will define the token for the admin's action(C U D) and the public action (R). If i generate an Admin::MyModel rails says i need an rake db:migrate, but i don't want this, because the fields are both in the myModel-table.... :-|

Comment: My suggestion would be to use only one token.  The logged-in user's access rights should direct them to either the public or admin version of the object.  This will also make it easier for your users to communicate with the admin users because they will be able to say "I have a problem with http://host/my_model/some-token" and the admin will be able to look up http://host/my_model/some-token to see the C/U/D version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My Idea is that no one must to login into the application. 
Each small webside wishes to create an account. Our app should work basically like doodle. No login, adminpage via admin_token an visitorpage like public_token. So i decided to create two unique token in mymodel. One for the admin only and one for the public visitors. Is this possible to realize in mymodel or should i create a complete user authentication (admin)?

Comment: In this way i want do that.
[link]doodle.com/poll/642cusz2s9vrc3h2taq2vkyy/admin[/link]

[link]doodle.com/poll/642cusz2s9vrc3h2[/link]
Is this one token or two? Because the admin-token is taq2vkyy

Comment: I think that it's not worth overriding the to_param method to achieve what you want to do.  Instead, use the standard url helper for your model and pass in the ID as the first parameter.  For example: my_model_path(id: my_model.public_token) or admin_my_model_path(id: my_model.token).  Reflexively, your controllers should do something like my_model = MyModel.find_by(public_token: params[:id]) || MyModel.find_by(token: params[:id]).

You may also consider the activerecord_any_of gem for the following query: MyModel.where.any_of({public_token: params[:id] }, { token: params[:id]})

Comment: It works fine. Thanks how can i set this question as resolved or answered?